# Why Firebase sends a 'Permission Denied' response when I try to authenticate from NextAuth.js?

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, next-auth

I have a `NextJS` project setup and I use `NextAuth.js` to add `Firebase Auth`.

I used the docs from `NextAuth.js` for adding Firebase Auth on the app but it's not working unless I set security rules on Firestore as `allow read, write: if true;`.

**What could be the problem from not working with** `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;`?

I have a `firebase.config.ts`:

```js
import { initializeApp, FirebaseOptions } from "firebase/app";
import {getAuth} from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig: FirebaseOptions = {
  apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.APP_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export {auth, app, firebaseConfig}
```

This is used in the `/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts` to conform to the NextAuth.js docs

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter"

import {firebaseConfig} from "../../../firebase.config"

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    })],
    adapter: FirestoreAdapter(firebaseConfig)
})
```

And then I just trigger the Authentication by using this:

```js
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <nav className="flex justify-between items-center p-4 bg-balmy-green">
      <div className="flex items-center">
        <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold pl-6 text-white">Tixer</h1>
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={() => signIn()}
        className="hover:text-gray-300 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
      >
        Sign In
      </button>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

In the terminal I see this:

```
[next-auth][error][adapter_error_getUserByAccount]
 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#adapter_error_getuserbyaccount 

Missing or insufficient permissions. {
  message: 'Missing or insufficient permissions.',
  stack: 'FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.',
  name: 'FirebaseError'
}
```